# Is it "to smell of" or "to smell with"?

Tags: prepositions, usage

I encountered a sentence *"It smelt **of** boiled cabbage and old rag mats.*" while I was reading a book.

Searching the Internet, I have discovered that in general, "to smell of" and "to smell with" are both OK. **Could you, please, explain me the difference, if any, between them? Can we use them both interchangeably?**

*P.S. Until now I have been using only "to smell with". For example "It smells with watermelon."*

Comment: You _smell with_ your nose, just like you _see with_ your eyes or _taste with_ your tongue. In this case, the pronoun "with" indicates the body part you are using to perform the action.

Comment: @CanadianYankee *"It smells with watermelon."* sounds weird now :)

Comment: "Searching the Internet, I have discovered that both variants are OK." The Internet is a very big place. Where did you read that "smelt with boiled cabbage" was OK?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I meant *"to smell with/of"*, sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: @StonePaul I edited your question to try to make that clearer. Feel free to edit again if I misrepresented what you were trying to say.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan That is OK, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To smell with* is not idiomatic.

The GloWBe corpus has no instances at all of "it smells/smelled/smelt with", but 205 of "it smells/smelled/smelt of".

The iWeb corpus has a few instances with "with" - 20 of them, against 1079 with "of".

Actually, looking at those 20, only 4 of them appear to be instances of what you are asking. Most of them are variations on "It tastes like it smells, with ...."

**Edit**: The previous paragraph might be misunderstood to say that we say "it tastes with ...". That is not the case either. Those examples could be something like "it tastes like it smells, of lemon". But they are all using "with" to add something to the taste, eg "It tastes just like it smells with a hint more of honey". So the "with" has its usual meaning of "together with".

Comment: When someone asks me something like "What does it smell like?", I should answer "It smells of watermelon". Thank you for *The corpus of Global Web-based English* by the way!

Comment: _To smell with_ is completely idiomatic if you say something like, "I smell with my nose." The issue is that _verb + with_ precedes the **means** by which that verb is done.

Comment: @CanadianYankee: yes, of course. But that is a different meaning.

Comment: @StonePaul: that's right.